# How to change my custom settings from code?

Tags: ios, swift, settings.bundle

This is my **Root.plist** file:

[image]

And this is visual presentation of that bundle:
[image]

All I need to do is change the value of Latest clean to appropriate date. I do it in code:

```
let PBOOrdersLatestCleanKey = "PBOOrdersLatestCleanKey"
let defaults = [PBOOrdersLatestCleanKey: PBODateFormatter(type: .DateAndTimeSimple).stringFromDate(NSDate())]      

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

But it is now working. The settings are still the same. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you didn't set the object to the specific key. You just registered the defaults but for undefined key.
Just try

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(PBODateFormatter(type: .DateAndTimeSimple).stringFromDate(NSDate()), forKey:PBOOrdersLatestCleanKey)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Good luck

Comment: Working. What is the difference?

Comment: The problem is you didn't set the object to the specific key. You just registered the defaults but for undefined key.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as solved if it works well. to help others users find the right answer.